# How to judge the request.user whether is AnonymousUser?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to jundge the request.user is AnonymousUser in Django?

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):

        if request.user:
            print("not AnonymousUser" ) # there I tried

        return Response(data="200", status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

You see, I tried `request.user` to check the user whether exist, but failed, always print the `not AnonymousUser`.
How to check it?

Comment: You can use `request.user.is_anonymous`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the user's `is_authenticated` method to check a user whether login：

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # Do something for logged-in users.
else:
    # Do something for anonymous users.
```

Thanks @Alasdair, after the Django v1.10 version, the `is_authenticated` is a attribute now. you can easy use `request.user.is_authenticated` to check it.

Comment: Note that in Django 1.10+ it's an attribute not a method: `if request.user.is_authenticated:`